# How to create super and sub class from JSON?

Tags: dart

I've been trying to figure out how to use a named constructor to construct super and sub classes from JSON. Below is my example with some notes on what I've tried in the `fromJson` method body. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

```
class Item {
  final String name;
  final int id;
  final String image;
  final double price;
  final bool available;

  Item(this.name, this.id, this.image, this.price, this.available);

  Item.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : name = json['name'],
        id = json['id'],
        image = json['image'],
        price = json['price'],
        available = json['available'];

}

class CartItem extends Item {
  final int quantity;

  CartItem({
    @required this.quantity,
    @required name,
    @required id,
    @required price,
    @required image,
    @required available

  }): super(id, name, image, price, available)
  
  CartItem.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) 
    : quantity = json['quantity'],
    // for whatever ever reason, super here seems to refer to CartItem
    // so this doesn't work
    super.name = json['name'],
    // calling 'name' without the super doesn't work either
    name = json['name']
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a the `super`'s `fromJson` constructor in the child class's `fromJson` constructor. You can pass the `Map` in the child directly to the `super` without issues. Ex:

```dart
CartItem.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) 
    : quantity = json['quantity'],
    super.fromJson(json);
```

Comment: Thanks! that appears to clear that error! However, with this code I get an error that says 'A Function Body must be provided' which is, lamentably, equally stupefying.

Comment: @JoshBowling I forgot a semicolon at the end of the constructor. This is also an issue present with your original `CartItem` constructors.